# MySQL LIMIT on a LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, mysql

My query:

```
   SELECT issues.*, 
          comments.author AS commentauthor, 
          comments.when_posted AS commentposted
     FROM issues
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
             FROM comments 
         ORDER BY when_posted DESC 
            LIMIT 1) AS comments ON issues.id=comments.issue
ORDER BY IFNULL(commentposted, issues.when_opened) DESC
```

My problem with it is the "LIMIT 1" on the third line. That limits all comments to only the newest one, so only issues with the newest comment will be reported back as having a comment at all.

If I removed the "LIMIT 1" part from there, I'd get a row for every comment in an issue, and that's not what I want. What I want is only the newest comment for each issue.

In any case, I'm not sure if my IFNULL part even works because that's not where I'm up to in debugging yet.

So how would I achieve what I wanted?

Comment: rexem - Your edit to my SQL code... the left spacing looks weird :c

Comment: Anyway it is much better than it was before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   SELECT issues.*, 
          comments.author AS commentauthor, 
          comments.when_posted AS commentposted
     FROM issues
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT c1.issue, c1.author, c1.when_posted
              FROM comments c1
           JOIN
           (SELECT c2.issue, max(c2.when_posted) AS max_when_posted           
              FROM comments c2
          GROUP BY issue) c3
            on c1.issue = c3.issue and c1.when_posted = c3.max_when_posted
          ) AS comments ON issues.id=comments.issue
 ORDER BY COALESCE(commentposted, issues.when_opened) DESC
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource. Oh dear.

Comment: Have you tested the query directly into `MySql` (at least to have the sql error message if there is one). That `php` error can mean many things.

Comment: phpMyAdmin says "#1052 - Column 'issue' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: And then we have "#1054 - Unknown column 'comments.author' in 'field list'". What is a 'field list' anyway?

Comment: fixed. the field list is the columns (fields) outputted by a select (i.e: between SELECT & FROM)

Comment: Brilliant, brilliant, brilliant, thank you very much! Now to figure out what all this SQL means... it looks pretty confusing right now...

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
   SELECT i.*,
          c.author AS commentauthor,
          c.when_posted AS commentposted
     FROM ISSUES i
LEFT JOIN COMMENTS c ON c.issue = i.id
     JOIN (SELECT c.issue,
                  MAX(c.when_posted) 'max_when_posted'
             FROM COMMENTS c
         GROUP BY c.issue) mwp ON mwp.issue = c.issue
                              AND mwp.max_when_posted = c.when_posted
 ORDER BY COALESCE(c.when_posted, i.when_opened) DESC
```

Comment: This works, but I have an issue in my database without any comments associated, and it isn't being listed. In any case, all these answers are somewhat... confusing. I've got a lot to learn... ._.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Since MySql does not have CTE's after all, try this:

```
SELECT i.*
    c.author AS CommentAuthor,
    c.when_posted AS CommentPosted
FROM Issues i
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT issue, MAX(when_posted) AS LastPostDate 
     FROM comments GROUP BY issue) ic ON ic.issue = i.id
LEFT JOIN Comment c ON c.issue = i.id AND c.when_posted = ic.LastPostDate  
ORDER BY COALESCE(ic.LastPostDate, issues.when_opened) DESC
```

Comment: Sadly, MySQL doesn't support the WITH clause.  The request has been in since 2006 :(